# Ruby separate large source files into multiple files

Tags: ruby, inheritance

I am writing a Ruby script which was supposed to be a small thing but has grown quite large, way to large to have everything crammed into one source file. So I am trying to separate the project into different files. I have four classes and I want to put each in its own separate source file.

**What I did:**

I moved all of the classes into their own files so now I have this

```
proj/GoogleChart.rb
proj/BarChart.rb
proj/PieChart.rb
proj/GroupedBarChart.rb
```

Now that they are in other files I am getting `uninitialized constant GoogleChart (NameError)` in all of my subclasses on the line where I inherit from GoogleChart, i.e.

```
require 'GoogleChart'
BarChart < GoogleChart
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Using ruby version 1.8.4

Also I have tried using the absolute path:

`require 'C:/Documents and Settings/proj/GoogleChart.rb'` and this is still producing a `NameError`

Comment: Do you use also Modules to build namespaces? Is there a 2nd GoogleChart.rb (or in other words: are you sure you load the correct GoogleChart.rb - maybe require_relative would be better)

Comment: I shouldve mentioned above, the Ruby version we have is 1.8.4 so `require_relative` isnt an option

Comment: What doesnt make sense is even trying to require the absolute path doesnt work. `require C:/Document and Settings/proj/BarChart.rb` still returns a `NameError`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby 1.8.x, the `.` is part of your load path. So you should at least try to debug that by including something like:

```
puts $:
require 'GoogleChart'
class BarChart < GoogleChart
end
```

and load that in an IRB session:

1. Open the session in your directory `proj`.
2. Enter there `require 'BarChart'`
3. Look at the result.

For me it is:

```
c:\apps\ruby\test\proj>irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'BarChart'
C:/Users/mliebelt/.pik/rubies/Ruby-187-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8
C:/Users/mliebelt/.pik/rubies/Ruby-187-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/i386-msvcrt
C:/Users/mliebelt/.pik/rubies/Ruby-187-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby
C:/Users/mliebelt/.pik/rubies/Ruby-187-p334/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8
C:/Users/mliebelt/.pik/rubies/Ruby-187-p334/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/i386-msvcrt
C:/Users/mliebelt/.pik/rubies/Ruby-187-p334/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
C:/Users/mliebelt/.pik/rubies/Ruby-187-p334/lib/ruby/1.8
C:/Users/mliebelt/.pik/rubies/Ruby-187-p334/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-mingw32
.
=> true
```

So the require is successful for me, and the `.` is part of the path (as it should). As you can see, I am working with Ruby 1.8.7, I don't know if anything has changed since 1.8.4 that is relevant here.

So please describe exactly how you run your file:

- Have you opened a shell to run the file?
- What is the current working directory of that shell?
- Do you run by double-clicking it?

It only works when you are in your `proj` directory and run there (with ruby in your shell  path) `ruby BarChart.rb`.

Comment: That also succeeds for me interactively, and the `.` is part of my load path: `c:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8|
c:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/i386-msvcrt|
c:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby|
c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8|
c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-mswin32| .` But for some reason It doesnt work when I go to run the file

Comment: Added at the end how to run the Ruby file. Please check that as well.

Comment: I get the NameError when I run from the shell and from SciTE

Comment: Have you tried to move the project files into a directory with no spaces in the path? Just a wild guess, so ...